# How do professionals retrieve data in an iPhone app ? (database)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, database, ipad

I have data that I store in a database server somewhere.

I want to access this data from my iphone.
How do I connect to a database server using objective-c?

As a side question, I'm not sure which database to use so recommendations on that subject would be welcome as well.

Comment: Do you store the data in the iphone itself (in that case the answer is SQLite), or do you store the data in a server somewhere?

Comment: That's not really a programming question. Stack Overflow questions generally focus on a specific technical problem, not a broad decision such as "which database to use." But most engineers use sqlite3 on iOS because it ships with every version of the OS. :)

Comment: I am **NOT** asking _which_ database to use, but generally how I would tackle such a problem. I read something about Core Data or something like that, and I read that MySQL is not supported in Objective-C. So as you see it indeed is a technical problem. I would also like to know how to implement a database into my code, maybe someone could give me a link to a tutorial. I just want to make sure I am doing it the right way, as I am pretty new to programming in Objective-C. @Johan : I don't want to store it on the iPhone, just read it from the database and output it (like text or so).

Comment: You never should connect to a database directly over the internet.  
Instead you use a webserver that serves as a front-end.  
Using that you can connect to any database server whatsoever. Your claim that objective-c cannot connect to a MySQL database is non-sense, but that's another matter.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I'll take a closer look at Core Data and maybe first try to do it via a MySQL database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to store data in IOS each with its own benefits and drawbacks. I recommend reading through the [IOS Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075) to find out the fundamentals about them.

IOS's [Managed Object Model](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMOM.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002328-SW1) is very powerful so you should have a thorough read of those sections, it allows you to have object representations of all entities within your persistent store (database).

Apple have also released an in-depth tutorial that makes use of the Managed Object Model and tools which you can find [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/01_StartingOut.html)